# css text decoration none not working in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, href

Here is the HTML and CSS code:

```css
#spanUpdBrowserSuggestions a {
    font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
}

#spanUpdBrowserSuggestions a:hover {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```

```html
<span name="spanUpdBrowserSuggestions" id="spanUpdBrowserSuggestions">
<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/new/" target="_new">Firefox</a><br></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.opera.com/download/" target="_new">Opera</a><br></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.google.com/chrome/index.html" target="_new">Chrome</a><br></li>
  <li><a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/downloads/ie" target="_new">Explorer</a><br></li>
</ul>                   
</span>
```

In Firefox, Opera, even IE it displays as it should: black links normally and red on hover. in Webkit-based browsers though (Google Chrome and Safari) it displays as normal blue links with underline.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Tested in Chrome, got black links with red hover. Your problem lies somewhere else.

Comment: [Agreed... it works](http://jsfiddle.net/FL6rG/)

Comment: yes, i had a <p> before the <span> which wasn't closed with </p> and that seemed to be the source of the problem... thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should not put block element inside an inline element, so you can not put an ul inside a span. try changing the span for some other element, like a div.